# ¿Porque en XAMPP si funciona y en IIS no?

Tags: php, xampp, servidor, iis, configuración

estoy en un proyecto de pago en linea con PHP y SQL Server, he creado todo lo necesario para ello y todas las pruebas y este proceso lo hice en XAMPP para ejecutarlo localmente pero la empresa usa IIS para sus paginas en publico, al querer montarlo solo me abre el Index todo bien sin errores pero al querer redireccionar a otra pagina me sale el error 404 como si no existiera los otros módulos que cree, es algún tema de configuración del servidor o el problema puede venir a raíz de mi código?

(En el entorno de XAMPP no presente ningún tipo de error y lo único especial es que uso PHP 7.4 el cual si lo monte bien en el IIS)

(Los URL son correctos, no se agrega ningún tipo de carácter o algo extraño al montarlo en IIS, monte la pagina en el intranet de la empresa, ahí usa XAMPP y pues ningún problema con el redireccionamiento)

Comment: Si es error 404, tu problema está en las ruta. Frecuentemente pasa que cuando desarrollas, el proyecto está en la raíz `http://localhost` y luego en producción está en una carpeta `http://nombre.com/carpeta`

Comment: De echo si modifique las rutas por eso mi dolor de cabeza que no logro comprender porque no funciona, yo tenia pensado algún configuración del servidor o similar :(

Comment: Yo probaría a mano varias rutas, tratando de encontrar, por ejemplo una imagen. Cuando la encuentres tendrás claro cuál debe ser la ruta correcta